# Using assembly attributes in F#

Tags: c#, f#, ironpython

I'm trying to translate the following C# example, which constructs an IronPython module, to F#.

```
using System;
using IronPython.Runtime;

[assembly: PythonModule("my_module", typeof(MyModule))]

public static class MyModule {
    public static void hello_world() {
        Console.WriteLine("hello world");
    }
}
```

Using PythonModule allows `from my_module import *`, among other things.

I am having trouble figuring out how to apply the PythonModule attribute in F#.  The F# documentation only talks about assembly attributes related to modules, and attached to do().  It's not clear to me how to define static classes that are interpreted as python modules, but I am not a C#/F#/IronPython expert.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have all the bits at hand to see if this works, but I would try

```
open System
open IronPython.Runtime

type MyModule = 
    static member hello_world() =
        Console.WriteLine("hello world")

module DummyModuleOnWhichToAttachAssemblyAttribute =
    [<assembly: PythonModule("my_module", typeof<MyModule>)>] 
    do ()
```

for starters.

Comment: This works. After adding the dll, `import my_module` works as expected.  The dummy module seems a little funny, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 6):

Haven't tested it but...

```
module MyModule 

open System
open IronPython.Runtime

let hello_world () =
    Console.WriteLine "Hello, World."

[<assembly: PythonModule("my_module", typeof<MyModule>)>] 
do ()
```

Same as Brian's, but without the dummy module.

Comment: I'm afraid that `typeof<MyModule>` won't work for `MyModule`, because it isn't a type, but a module (at least it didin't, last time I checked). This is an annoying limitation, because writing F# functions instead of static classes would be just great!

Comment: (I would almost consider using some really nasty workaround to get this working, because it would be just so nice to write simple F# functions - e.g. you could write the `assembly` attribtue in C# and then use "ILMerge" to merge them into one)

Comment: I also don't want to use a module directly, because I can't overload hello_world.  By using static methods I get overloaded functions in Python.

Comment: @Tomas: Ah, you are right... of course, if modules were types, functors wouldn't be far behind, would they?